# why is my class array element behaving like a pointer? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, class, pointers

I have this short windows form application code that i cannot get to work properly. It uses an instance of a class (as a temporary storage place) to populate an array of the same class type. It has a button and a textbox. If you press the button, the text is saved in the *Name* member and added to the array.
If the *Name* is taken by another array member, it should show a message "name taken!" and not add it to the array. The problem is that this condition check is always true!
if we type in "Marry", the debugger shows that

```
 if (examleArray[i].Name == temp.Name)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ("Marry" == "Marry")
```

as if one is pointing to the other. Why is this? how do i fix it? thank you!

```
namespace errorexample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        example temp = new example();
        example[] examleArray = new example[10];
        int examleArrayIndex = 0;
        bool NameTaken = false;

        public Form1()
        {  InitializeComponent();  }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            temp.Name = textBox1.Text;         
            NameTaken = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < (examleArrayIndex); i++)
            {
                if (examleArray[i].Name == temp.Name)
                {
                    NameTaken = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Name taken!");
                }

            }

            if (NameTaken == false)
            {
                examleArray[examleArrayIndex] = temp;
                examleArrayIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    public class example {
        public string Name;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Because there is only one instance of `example` in your form, you keep reusing it

Comment: Because you have an array of references that all point to the same `example` object since you only create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `temp` object, and you add keep adding it to the array.  It's the same `temp` since you never create a `new` one.  I've rewritten it for you:

```
 List<example> examleArray = new List<example>();
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (examleArray.Any(e=>e.Name == textBox1.Text))
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Name taken!");
   } else {
     examleArray.Add(new example { Name = textBox1.Text });
   }
 }
```

I've also converted your fixed array into a List so you don't ever accidentally try and add 11 names and then blow up.  And I've converted your search to LINQ to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

move temp object initialization inside the click event, otherwise you are updating same object

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            example temp = new example();
            temp.Name = textBox1.Text;         
            NameTaken = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < (examleArrayIndex); i++)
            {
                if (examleArray[i].Name == temp.Name)
                {
                    NameTaken = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Name taken!");
                }

            }

            if (NameTaken == false)
            {
                examleArray[examleArrayIndex] = temp;
                examleArrayIndex++;
            }
        }
```

you can use List

```
List<string> example =
        new List<string>();

if(example.Contains(textBox1.Text))
{ 
  MessageBox.Show("Name taken!");
}else
{
  example.Add(textBox1.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only create one `example` object. You are putting multiple references to the same object into the array. One solution is to create a new `example` object to put in the array:

```
public class example {
    public string Name;
    public example( string name ){
        Name = name;
    }
}

//...
examleArray[examleArrayIndex] = new example( temp.Name );
```